# Not able to save kable extra table as png in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, png, kable, kableextra

I have this code in R Markdown and I'd like to be able to export my kable extra table to .png to add it to my word document (knitting as word file does not work), but this option to save as pdf or png is working.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)
filtering <- data.frame(
  "1" = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes"),
  "2" = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes"),
  "3" = c("14-28 days", "28-84 days", ">84 days"),
  "4" = c("No/I don't know", "No/I don't know", "No/I don't know"),
  "5" = c("Valid", "Valid", "Valid"),
  "6" = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes"),
  "7" = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes")
)


filtering %>%
  kbl(align = "l", escape = F) %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Times New Roman") %>%
  row_spec(0, background = "#B2DACC") %>%
  save_kable(file = "Variables.png")
```

And I get this error:

```
Auto configuration failed
140507277977536:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(libproviders.so): libproviders.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
140507277977536:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
140507277977536:error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:MODULE_LOAD_DSO:error loading dso:conf_mod.c:285:module=providers, path=providers
140507277977536:error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name:conf_mod.c:222:module=providers
Error in webshot::webshot(file_temp_html, file, ...) :
webshot.js returned failure value: 1
```

I already looked at other stack overflow questions but none of them solve my problem.

```
packageVersion("webshot")
[1] ‘0.5.4’

 packageVersion("kableExtra")
[1] ‘1.3.4’
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I am using the same package versions and can produce the .png without any problems. Have you done `webshot::install_phantomjs()`?

Comment: With:
`Sys.setenv("OPENSSL_CONF"="/dev/null")` and 
`webshot::install_phantomjs(force = TRUE)`. Thank you!